# JSP Editor for Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, jsp, syntax-highlighting, eclipse-juno

I installed Eclipse Juno recently and I see that JSP files are not properly code highlighted. Everything appears as if it is a normal text file.

The previous versions of eclipse used to be fine. Am I missing something ?

Comment: What Eclipse Juno have you downloaded (Classic, for JavaEE or what)?

Comment: Is your Project a Java Web Project?

Comment: @PeterRader _ It is a Java Dynamic web project and I have downloaded JavaEE version

Comment: `JavaEE` or `Eclipse for JavaEE`?

Answer (score 2):

Try to <kbd>Right-Click</kbd> the .jsp-file and choose `Open With`>`JSP Editor`.

This should do the Trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you've installed Juno EE it should support .jsp editor.

Most probably, your Eclipse is "starting" with java less than v1.6 (for me it was as well, I have 1.3, 1.5, 1.6 javas installed; default was 1.5 and Eclipse was starting with it automatically)

I solved same problem with below way:

**1)** Right click on Juno **shortcut** and click **Properties**

**2)** In the **field "Target"**

You already should have something like below:

"D:\PROGRAM INSTALL\eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32\eclipse\eclipse.exe"

**Add to the end of that line** one more command as below (show to Eclipse with which java version it should start)

**-vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin\java.exe"**

My target looks like below:

**"D:\PROGRAM INSTALL\eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32\eclipse\eclipse.exe" -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin\java.exe"**

**3)** Start Eclipse with changed target using your shortcut

**4)** On .jsp file now you will be able to chose "Open with --> JSP Editor"

Answer (score 0):

It is because of Eclipse do not know what JDK do you like to use.

1. Rightcklick the Project, select `Configure` -> Convert the Project to an `Faceted Project`.
2. Go to Project `Properties`->`Project Facets` and check `Java` with a version of your choice.

Comment: How to convert a project to Faceted Project ? What is a Faceted Project ?

Comment: Usually the convertion of a Project from `Java Dynamic Web Project` to a `Faceted Project` will result in a `Java Dynamic Web Project with Faceted Project`. It does not drop the `Java Dynamic Web Project`! 
The Faceted Project can prevent the using of incompatible Frameworks.

Comment: Thank You ! But I guess it needs Java 1.6 or later.

Comment: I don't understand. Is Java 1.6 not in the list? Did you install 1.6 JDK? Does eclipse know where?

Comment: We use java 1.5 in our project. To maintain consistency in work spaces, we are not allowed to change the version. So that's the problem.

Comment: You think the eclipse-developer disallow you to write JSP on 1.5? Right click on the java-facet and choose `Change Version`. Hey seriously: you looks like a pessimistic one :D. Trust in eclipse!